# NodeJS exec mkdir not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, mkdir

The following code makes the **Vagrantfile** in `c:/api/iaas` instead of making a new file using `mkdir` and then adding **Vagrantfile** to that folder.

The `mkdir` part should create the folder, but it does not create it. How to fix it so it creates the folder then adds the **Vagrantfile** to it?

> Desired: `c:/api/iaas/ubuntu/Vagrantfile`
>
> What happens now: `c:/api/iaas/Vagrantfile`

### Code:

```
exec(function (err, boxes) {
  if (err) return next(err);

  exec('mkdir ' + box.boxos, {
      cwd: 'c:/api/iaas/'
  }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      // work with result
  });

  exec('vagrant init ' + box.boxos + '/' + box.boxversion, {
      cwd: 'c:/api/iaas/' + box.boxos + '/'
  }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      // work with result
  });

  res.redirect('/profile/');
});
```

Comment: Why are you not using [fs.mkdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback)? Also, in your current code, you don't wait for `mkdir` to end before starting vagrant. As a last point, you seems to have redefined exec before that snippet of code.

Comment: like this? `fs.mkdir('c:/api/iaas/' + box.boxos, (err, folder) => {
                  console.log(folder);
                });` doesn't work.. And how do I wait till mkdir is done before it continues?

Comment: `fs.mkdir`'s callback doesn t return the folder, only a possible error. As of your second question, by learning how to use callbacks.

Comment: There is a reason we don't use fs.mkdir, because we need to do mkdir -p and we don't want to add one more dependency. Oh, I just had a quick check, the latest version of nodejs mkdir has the option of recursive. Looks like the end of the life the popular package mkdirp.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easy solution was to `nmp install mkdirp` and

```
app.get('/addbox/:id', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        Box.findById(req.params.id, function (err, box) {
            console.log('addbox clicked');

            var user_id = req.user.id;

            //            var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
            //            mkdirp('c:/api/iaas/' + box.boxos, function (err) {});

            Box.
            find({
                user_id: user_id
            }).
            sort('-updated_at').
            exec(function (err, boxes) {
                if (err) return next(err);

                var box_path = 'c:/api/iaas/' + req.user.local.username + '/' + box.boxos + '/' + box.boxversion + '/' + box.id + '/'

                new Instance({
                    user_id: req.user.id,
                    box_id: box.id,
                    box_path: box_path,
//                    ssh: req.body.ssh,
                    ssh: "ssh-",
                    username: req.user.local.username,
                    password: req.user.local.password
                }).save(function (err, instance, count) {
                    if (err) return next(err);



                    mkdirp(box_path, function (err) {
                        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
                        exec('vagrant init ' + box.boxos + '/' + box.boxversion, {
                            cwd: box_path
                        }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                            // work with result
                        });

                        res.redirect('/profile/');
                    });


                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Until the day `mkdirp` will not be finished in time and you ll have a near impossible to track error. Almost all your code should be in mkdirp's callback.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "intil the day mkdirp will not be finished in time"?

Comment: node.js is asynchronous, so written like that, you start mkdirp, and start your request to Box at the same time. And at the end of the request you start vagrant. It is a race condition, and if, for whatever reason, mkdirp didn't finished before Box return, you will start vagrant on a non existent folder.
All the `Box.find(...` part should be inside the callback of mkdirp.

Comment: I ve eddited my answer to reflect how your code should look like, just used `fs.mkdir` instead of `mkdirp`

Comment: Thanks, i've changed mkdirp yesterdaynight and have updated my answer. My solution works great for me. I'm not saying your solution is not working, but I have not tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

since both the steps are dependent, there is a need to carryout both the steps sequentially.
Use `fs.mkdirSync` to create directory and then proceed with dependent logic.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Another option would be to handle the subsequent dependent logic within the callback of `fs.mkdir`

Comment: The sync version will block the event loop, and is bad advice unless there is a really good reason. Using the async version and correctly handle callback will be far more useful and correct.

Comment: made the edit.first one is not a bad option, it depends on usecase

Comment: Yes, but since OP seems to not be experienced enought in node.js to differenciate between valid and bad usecase, and the overwhelming majority of invalid usecase for the `sync` variant, the async function should be the first option, not the last.

Comment: agreed.what if it is being run as a cron job??and nothing else is happening at that time.better to make it simple, but point taken, good if he op knows both.

Answer (score -1):

```
var user_id = req.user.id;

var fs = require('fs');

fs.mkdir('c:/api/iaas/' + box.boxos, function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('error in mkdir: ' + err);
    } else {
        Box.
        find({
            user_id: user_id
        }).
        sort('-updated_at').
        exec(function (err, boxes) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            var exec = require('child_process').exec;
            exec('vagrant init ' + box.boxos + '/' + box.boxversion, {
                cwd: 'c:/api/iaas/' + box.boxos
            }, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                // work with result
            });

            res.redirect('/profile/');
        });
    }
});
```

You should really look at books about asynchronous programming.